# rounding off to next multiple of 5 in python

Tags: python-3.x

when we round 67 to its next multiple of 5 the answer is 70
where as when we round 64 the ans should be 65 but it comes to be 70

I looked for logic in C++
where I found `5*(grades[i]+4)/5)` for calculation of next multiple of 5

my code implemented in python is:

```
ground=[]
grades=[73,64,67,38,33]
for i in range(len(grades)):
    r=5*(round((grades[i]+4)/5))
    ground.append(r)
print(ground)
```

expected output:`[75,65,70,40,35]`
but
actual output:`[75,70,70,40,35]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `//` operator (or `int`) instead of `round`:

```
ground = []
grades = [73, 64, 67, 38, 33]
for i in range(len(grades)):
    r = 5 * ((grades[i] + 4) // 5)
    ground.append(r)
print(ground)
```

Output:

```
[75, 65, 70, 40, 35]
```

Comment: Be careful, this will fail if we ever allow grades such as `70.5`

Answer (score 1):

Try this, This can be an optimised solution:

```
ground=[]
grades=[73,64,67,38,33]
for i in range(len(grades)):
    temp = 5 - grades[i] % 5
    ground.append(grades[i] + temp)
print(ground)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use modulo arithmetic on negative numbers to your advantage for this.

```
def round_up(n, base):
    return n + (-n % base)

grades= [73, 64, 67, 38, 33]
rgrades = [round_up(n, 5) for n in grades] # [75, 65, 70, 40, 35]
```

This works on `float` and other number types.

```
round_up(70.5, 5) # 75.0
```